# How to avoid imaginary numbers as solutions from Sqrt?

Tags: equation-solving

test function is the answer that I get from calculating the eigenvalues of a matrix. I need to calculate the square root of it. After I substitute the values for qx and qy, I am expanding it with respect to a1 and a2. I am not expecting imaginary values. Can anybody help with how to use Sqrt function so that it does not result in and imaginary answer?

```
 test[α1_, α2_, qx_, 
 qy_] := {0.5 (2.6 qx^2 α1 + 1.9 qy^2 α1 + 
 4.5 qx^2 α2 + 4.5 qy^2 α2 - 
 1. √(3.5 qx^4 α1^2 - 3.6 qx^2 qy^2 α1^2 + 
     0.1 qy^4 α1^2 + 8.4 qx^4 α1 α2 - 
     23.6 qx^2 qy^2 α1 α2 + 
     1.6 qy^4 α1 α2 + 5.0 qx^4 α2^2 - 
     30.4 qx^2 qy^2 α2^2 + 5.0 qy^4 α2^2)), 
0.5 (2.6 qx^2 α1 + 1.875` qy^2 α1 + 
 4.5 qx^2 α2 + 
 4.5 qy^2 α2 + √(3.5 qx^4 α1^2 - 
    3.6 qx^2 qy^2 α1^2 + 0.1 qy^4 α1^2 + 
    8.4 qx^4 α1 α2 - 
    23.6 qx^2 qy^2 α1 α2 + 
    1.6 qy^4 α1 α2 + 5.0 qx^4 α2^2 - 
    30.3 qx^2 qy^2 α2^2 + 5.0 qy^4 α2^2))};


foo = Sqrt[test[a1, a2, qx, qy]];


Series[foo, {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}] /. {qx -> 1, 
qy -> 1.2} // PowerExpand
```

Comment: Often using arbitrary precision numbers avoid the problems with round off errors near zero

Comment: Thanks but how do I take care of that? I just rounded of the numbers here for simplicity. I have the machine precision in my code but I still get imaginary numbers

Comment: Maybe try using Surd in place of Sqrt.

Comment: I did that. I get real numbers under some conditions, and I also get Indeterminate answer. but, a1 and a2 should be real all over.

Comment: Sqrt[Abs[expr]] is probably easiest if you’re sure the only way that expr can be negative is from round of error when it’s supposed to be ~zero. Sqrt[Threshold [expr, …]] might be even better but I’d have to look up Threshold[] which I can’t do right now.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that Threshold does not work in this case because I have variables and it gives me error. but it would be a good option if I knew how to fix it. I get the error that I do not have a non-empty or rectangular list of variables